# Get variable from Controller to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get a variable from the controller over to the model. Its the value of a checkbox passed up from the View. I cant see it in the controller (0 or 1) and just need to get it to the model. I have seen tons of examples on here but none of them seem to work for me. Maybe its something about the Ruby environment we have setup? Its a Rails 5 environment.
Here is what I have tried so far and the errors it gives in the logs:

Controller:

```
 @vin = Vehicle.create!
 @results = @vin.myvin!(params[:vehicle][:vincheck])
```

Model:

```
 def myvin!(localvin)
    logger.info "MADE IT INTO VIN"
 end
```

Error in development.log:

```
 AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action.
```

I'm not calling render or redirect!! Just trying to call the method in the model.

I have also tried a variation like:

Controller:

```
 Vehicle.myvin(params[:vehicle][:vincheck])
```

Model:

```
 def self.myvin(localvin)
    logger.info "MADE IT INTO VIN"
 end
```

But regardless... I always get that render error in the logs!

I have tried instantiating a new object:

Controller:

```
 Vehicle.new(params[:vehicle][:vincheck])
```

Model:

```
 attr_reader :localvin

 def initialize(localvin)
    logger.info "MADE IT INTO VIN"
 end
```

When I do that I get:

```
 500wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
 Short Stack

 app/models/vehicle.rb:25:in 'initialize'
 app/controllers/vehicles_controller.rb:84:in 'new'
```

Anyone have any thoughts on how I can get this data over? Maybe it has something to do with the Vehicle Model itself? In the controller it gets instantiated at different places. 
For example:

```
 def index
    @vehicles = Vehicle.active
 end

 def create  
     #this is where I am putting all my code
     #not really sure how this is getting created since there was no
     #initialize in the code before I added one
     @vehicle = Vehicle.new(vehicle_params.merge(
        created_by_id: current_user.id,
        created_by_name: current_user.name,
        deleted: false))

  end
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you put a debugger in your controller to see what the params are when coming in? From your second error it sounds like you're not actually getting the vin

Comment: I can print out params[:vehicle][:vincheck] and verify that it does have the value I want before I try to call the model. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Where in the Vehicles Controller are the Vehicle.create! and .myvin! methods being called? Can you post the entire controller? Also, you should instantiate a new vehicle in the new action not in the create action which is a POST action by default. You do not need to create an initialize method in the model, Rails will do that for you.

Comment: All of my code was in the create method above since that is what is fired when I hit submit on the page. I did try a "new" but that didn't seem to work either. Thanks for the info on initialize. If I do the Vehicle.new(params[:vehicle][:vincheck]) from the controller... how do I then access that from the Model (since I am not creating initialize)?  Thanks!

Comment: You have to tell the initializer what attribute you're passing in. If you just pass in a value it won't know which attribute it's for. If the attribute on that table is vincheck then it should look like this: @ vehicle = Vehicle.new(vincheck: params[:vehicle][:vincheck]) That will instantiate an object but it will not be saved until you call save on it in the create action. @ vehicle.save, then you can access that attribute from the object @ vehicle.vincheck